# SAP HANA Modeler view in Eclipse IDE Insufficient privilege (EXECUTE on REPOSITORY_REST)

Tags: eclipse, hana

I am attempting to connect [SAP HANA Schema via the Eclipse IDE](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?c597f8231b4e463da0dcc3095ea139b7.html). I have followed (and double checked) instructions to setup SAP HANA Cloud trial and to configure Eclipse for SAP HANA Cloud Platform tools.

When I add cloud system in HANA Modeler view in Eclipse IDE, it shows an error under the content folder of Systems tab. A screenshot of the error is included below.

> Insufficient privilege (EXECUTE on REPOSITORY_REST)

Schema is setup on SAP Hana Cloud Platform Trial with the following settings:

```
>Type: Schema
>Database System: HANA (shared)
>Version: 1.00.97.03.1443520413
>Bindings: 1 available
>Size(Used): 0 Byte
```

Data Source Bindings settings for above Schema are:

```
>Data Source: DEFAULT
>Java Application: hanasb
```

Screenshot of error:

[image: Link to Image of Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite being compatible with SAP HANA and SAP BW, Eclipse Neon is not compatible with SAP HANA Cloud. Eclipse Mars is required to add systems from the SAP HANA Cloud.

[Compatibility Documentation from SAP Development Tools](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/)

Comment: Neon now connects without any problems to HCP. However, I don't think this is the problem here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have created a HANA schema (option HANA shared). However, this does not support XS applications. You need to create a HANA database instead (option HANA MDC trial).